# Boom mic in Shot

Tags: boom, microphone, mistakes-blunders-mishaps

I came across this video and wondered how often the boom mic is in shot.  I was thinking we could start a thread for examples.

[youtube]ATIj8z4Nsl0[/youtube]

Answer (score 1):

I remember as a kid seeing the boom in the shot in Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom (the card game between Indie and Short Round in the woods the boom drops in for a second) and pointing it out to my dad and asking what it was.

He had no idea. He thought it was an animal or something.

Answer (score 0):

haha greaet video :) I think they're in shot a lot. They can just get taken out in post quite easily though.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the same, but I remember an episode of 24 (somewhere early in the first season) where the A camera pans a little too quick and too far to one side and you can quite clearly see the B camera operator dodge out of the way.

I guess they didn't realize until they were editing.

Answer (score 0):

Moscow Heat (2004) there was a boom that doesn't just graze the top of the frame, it dips in like the sound guy slipped.  The movie was hilariously bad up to that point, so that just made us roll with laughter even more.

On a related note, during the "I'm porn dialog without any sex" movie Wild Man (1989), there is an awesome scene where someone takes a dive off of a balcony and you see someone toss a mattress across the frame for them to land on.  I believe there were some booms in that movie too.

I'm surprised when I see booms or crew in the shot in movies made even in the past few years.. it's just not that hard, even for an amateur, to mask it out.

Comment: Three men and a baby movie said their was a ghost in the shot but maybe it was just the kid who went to get coffee for everyone and was stuck in the middle of the shot: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vF2f__k0Pnw&feature=related

Comment: @Utopia - I've seen that before and just saw this link posted in the youtube clip explaining the "ghost". http://www.castleofspirits.com/threemenbaby.html

Answer (score 0):

Epic boom dip is in Rocky Horror Picture Show just in the beginning at the church.. EPIC

Answer (score 0):

Watched some reruns of Just Shoot me and have more than once seem the boom dipped in from the top of the frame. I took down the ep no, but deleted it when I saw it happen a couple more times. Seems like no one really notices when the script is good. It's a pretty funny show.